# Using ActiveRecord's scope instruction to return a single result

Tags: ruby, activerecord, scope, simplification

I have the following class that works fine in my unit tests but I feel it could be simpler.

```
class License < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, lambda {
    where("active_from <= ?", Date.today).order("version_number DESC")
  }
end

def current_license
  return License.active.first
end

public :current_license
```

I have tried appending the `.first` into the `lambda` clause but that causes an error.

How do I tell the `scope` I only want the first result, and thus eliminate the method `current_license` completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a method, and you can get this:

```
class License < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.current_license
    return License.where("active_from <= ?", Date.today).order("version_number DESC").first
  end

end
```

As for the number of results, try to add a `.limit(1)`. For more info, have a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

Comment: :-) well yep that works and is simpler. One question, is the `self.` needed there or is that just a style thing?

Comment: The self is needed, as this is a class method.

Comment: really? I've not seen that before.

Comment: More generally however, is there actually any way to make a scoped query return a single result?

Comment: @Dave Sag, please check now with the `.limit` method.

Comment: More specifically, the AR::Base `scope` method can only return collections. If you call `first` inside of a lambda passed to the `scope` macro, you get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'klass'`